# Are parallel multithreaded async EF calls safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have tried to research this topic but most questions / answer I see here go against what I would believe to be true or are conflicting in their response - possibly because they are a couple of years old.

If I have a multi threaded environemnt (two use cases: ASP.NET and some other windows service).  If I run two EF6 async calls at the same time but using separate `UnitOfWork` / `DbContext` will it throw? In practice it never seems to but that goes against previous answers here on SO?

Previously I had thought that as long as the `DbContext` wasn't shared then any locking would be he Databases prerogative.  Thus would only block if the table / query blocked.

i.e. Lets assume both of these two calls happen at the exact same time.  What will happen?

```
// Request 1
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
  var list = await uow.GetMeSomething().ToListAsync();
}

// Request 2
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
  var list = await uow.GetMeSomething().ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Safe, probably, if you use multiple contexts, or MARS. Useful? Not often. They are far more likely to *lower* throughput. What is the actual problem you want to solve? Are you trying to improve performance? Or do you have concurrency issues and think that DbContext is the issue?

Comment: IMO they are not, but if you want to fetch a large list of objects e.g. 1 000 000 rows, you can create threads for each 10 000 and compose them into one big list when threads are finished.

Comment: What is MARS? I'm not sure what you mean by "seldom useful" and "lower throughput"; could you elaborate?

Comment: @BMaximus multiple contexts *are* safe, because they are different connections. But that also means greater contention in the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We have a system that reads and writes LOTS of data all the time.  Async / await should allow the system to process messages faster than it would have done without async await? In my testing locally I already get far greater processing rate using async.

Comment: @Chris more connections means more contention for the same locks on the server side. After a certain threshold, the number of transactions per second *falls* as you increase the number of concurrent queries. That's why connection pooling is so important, or why long connections are harmful.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos wont argue on that, but whats the point on having 2 different connections and fetching same data 2 times? just split the overall load into multiple threads.

Comment: @chris you are asking different questions. `async/await` doesn't change how queries are processed on the server. It means your web service doesn't waste threads waiting for the same response. It is a *good* thing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed.  But EF manages the pool and UOWs are only kept alive long enough to do one job then are deleted so they are not kept around long at all.  Plus our database is enterprise level so can probably handle lots of connections.

Comment: If you use different contexts, how this can be a problem? You just use two separate connecitons to database, and database obviously can handle concrurrent requests.

Comment: @evk This is what I thought, but if you look around at other SO questions they have conflicting (or at the very least non-clear) answers!

Comment: Can you provide examples of such answers?

Comment: @Chris you are mixing up different issues. The *database* server is one thing. The web application is another system. Of course you can have a lot of *database* connections, but all of them cause contention. You asked about the *web-side* though. `async/await` is safe

Comment: @Evk just in this discussion, we got confusion of database locks, web-side concurrency, asynchronous execution (they are *different*)

Comment: @Chris `async/await` doesn't deal with multi-threaded execution, but *asynchronous* execution. The *same* connection/context is used in an asynchronous manner. That means that your service thread doesn't block waiting for a response. That's a huge benefit in high-traffic web sites both in requests/sec that can be served by a single machine *and* CPU - blocking typically involves spinwaits before escalating to full blocking

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Could you please assist  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098375/async-await-and-continuewith-for-a-entityframework-database-process-method-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. You can have two (or any number of) simultaneous requests as long as they use different `DbContext`s.

Doing concurrent database requests may not get you much, though. In particular, if both requests are hitting the same spinning rust-style drive, then I wouldn't expect much speed increase, if any.

Comment: Thank you.  If this is the case though why did EF put async support in? I thought that as long as queries hit different tables in the DB (i.e. no locking occurred) I would be able to get a higher throughput.  It certainly seems to be the case anecdotally.

Comment: @Chris: Async allows the *calling* application to free up a thread.